# Is the Amazon rain forest man-made?

Tags: biology, environment

An article in *[the Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2002/03/1491/2445/)* quotes several experts who claim that the Amazon rainforest is the remnants of planted and cultivated orchards and farms, and that the land is not naturally conducive to this type of growth.

> Planting their orchards, the first Amazonians transformed large swaths
>   of the river basin into something more pleasing to human beings. In a
>   widely cited article from 1989, William Balée, the Tulane
>   anthropologist, cautiously estimated that about 12 percent of the
>   nonflooded Amazon forest was of anthropogenic origin—directly or
>   indirectly created by human beings. In some circles this is now seen
>   as a conservative position. "I basically think it's all
>   human-created," Clement told me in Brazil. He argues that Indians
>   changed the assortment and density of species throughout the region.
>   So does Clark Erickson, the University of Pennsylvania archaeologist,
>   who told me in Bolivia that the lowland tropical forests of South
>   America are among the finest works of art on the planet. "Some of my
>   colleagues would say that's pretty radical," he said, smiling
>   mischievously. According to Peter Stahl, an anthropologist at the
>   State University of New York at Binghamton, "lots" of botanists
>   believe that "what the eco-imagery would like to picture as a
>   pristine, untouched Urwelt [primeval world] in fact has been managed
>   by people for millennia." The phrase "built environment," Erickson
>   says, "applies to most, if not all, Neotropical landscapes."

Is there any evidence that supports this position?

Edit - This is [a link to a paper](http://ethnobiology.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/JoE/9-1/Balee.pdf) that may be what the Atlantic Article was referring to. (thanks Oddthinking)

Comment: I believe [this is the paper](http://ethnobiology.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/JoE/9-1/Balee.pdf) being referred to.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I didn't read it carefully enough. Feel free to change back; I think this title covers it okay.

Comment: That is incredibly interesting if true.

Comment: About 70% of the Amazon forest is *unexplored*.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi: Surely that's *unexplored by people wearing trousers*: the indigenous inhabitants presumably consider it sufficiently explored for their needs.

Comment: @dmckee nope, maybe that's not the correct figure, but it's considered unexplored by man. You probably remember a news report a few years back that an uncontacted tribe was found, completely isolated from civilization since no-one-knows. It's pretty hard to move in the jungle.

Comment: @dmckee also, most indigenous people nowadays wear trousers. They also smoke, drink and gamble, thanks to modern civilization!

Comment: @Ricardo: Do you mean *[this unconnected tribe](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4840/is-the-tribe-meets-white-man-for-the-first-time-video-fake)*?

Comment: The easy-reading book "The Lost City of Z" (http://www.amazon.com/The-Lost-City-Deadly-Obsession/dp/0385513534) promotes the idea of a large civilization in the Amazon basin that had considerable ecological impact. It's a dynamite read.

Comment: @Oddthinking Papua Nova Guine is in another continent, 17.000km from the Amazon. This is the tribe: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLErPqqCC54, here is video of first contact with such a tribe (not sure it's the same): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUDqf2UDhqk. They estimate about 70 other uncontacted tribes in the Amazon.

Comment: @Ricardo: Whoops. That link was to a PNG tribe? I didn't watch the video again, and I had forgotten. Sorry. I do know the difference, though! PNG is just around the corner (e.g. 3000 km) from me.

Comment: The title and the cited claim are inconsistent. It would help to reword the title. Also, is the claim that 12% was previously cultivated or otherwise disturbed by humans, or that without this disturbance another ecosystem would be present?

Comment: This is a very interesting subject but it appears to be an open question at this point. +1, but I am not sure it is suitable for the site.

Comment: @David - There is a notable claim about about a scientific theory.  What would make it unsuitable for this site?  As for the claim: *I basically think it's all human-created* directly from the quoted text.

Comment: @chad unsuitable in that it is an open question, there is currently insufficient evidence to determine if it is true or false. The text makes multiple claims, so it would be best to clarify which is being tested.

Comment: @David - I would refer you to [this meta discussion](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/176/3126) *Answerable, in this particular context, is not meant to be understood as a ban on questions where the answer is "we don't know."*

Comment: I would say that given the incredible amount of fauna present in the Amazon, and how incredibly adapted many species are to that particular ambiance and to each other, it would be highly improbable that the forest is man-made. Most of the Amazon is unexplored by modern civilization, and previous civilizations had major contact with it. But to this extent? I doubt it

Comment: @Paradox - I agree totally.  Which is why i posted the question.

Comment: @dmckee, there being uncontacted tribes living in the Amazon constitutes pretty backwards evidence for it being "unexplored by man" unless of course your postulating the colonialist view that these tribes are somehow not also "man".

Comment: @blahblah Er...that's my point. If they are then then it is silly to claim it is "unexplored by man".

Answer (score 9):

According to a recent [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0122njp) documentary,

> As more trees are felled, the story of a far less natural Amazon is
>   revealed - enormous manmade structures, even cities, hidden for
>   centuries under what was believed to be untouched forest. All the time
>   archaeologists are discovering ancient, highly fertile soils that can
>   only have been produced by sophisticated agriculture far and wide
>   across the Amazon basin. This startling evidence sheds new light on
>   long-dismissed accounts from the very first conquistadors of an Amazon
>   teeming with people

The programme page doesn't contain explicit references to the research quoted, but I'm sure the programme team would respond to questions.

Comment: +1 for more evidence to support the theory.  I do not think this fully answers the question but it could be a piece of the answer.

Comment: That's not a surprise. Amazon idians did not know about iron and the main tool to put down trees was fire. There's a tribe in that region called "Kaiapo" which literally means "with fire in hands". They may have burnt the forest to build their homes and then left after sometime.

I highly doubt about the "sophisticated agriculture". Natives didn't even invented the whell at the time, how can I belive they had "sophisticated agriculture"?

Comment: @HerberthAmaral: "how can I belive" You can believe because you, having not studied the issue yourself, are told by an expert that it was so. I recommend you start believing things experts tell you, or you'd have to forget a lot of other counterintuitive things that are true but that you've never experienced. (Quantum Mechanics, Relativity, Induction, Ideal Gas Law, elemental periodicity etc.)

Comment: @medivh I hope you're joking.

Comment: @HerberthAmaral Not at all